# IdentityServer4 claims are not part of the token on hybrid flow

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm trying to build a hybrid flow, and have claims on the returned access token with IdentityServer4. I'm using the [QuickStart UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI) controlles.

In my `AccountController` after the user was authenticated successfully, I have the following code which signs him in:

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync("anon@nymous.com", "anon@nymous.com", null, new Claim("MyName", "Ophir"));
```

In the MVC website that is causing this flow, on the page I want to "protect" I have the following code:

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult RestrictedMvcResource()
{
       var token = _httpContext.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result;
       var identity = User.Identity;
       return View();
}
```

After a successful login, the debugger hits this code fine and I'm getting the access token.

The problem is that if I decode my access token (I'm using https://jwt.io/) I see the name and subject, but I do not see the `MyName` claim that I have defined.

(I have another flow in my system for `client_credentials` which does return the claims on the token - but it uses a different code flow).

How do I return the claims on the token for the hybrid flow?

**EDIT:**

Solving this problem was a combination of 2 things:

1. Implementing `IProfileService` as suggested in (selected) answer. here's my implementation:

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        context.AddRequestedClaims(context.Subject.Claims);

        foreach (Claim claim in context.Subject.Claims)
        {
            if (context.IssuedClaims.Contains(claim))
                continue;

            context.IssuedClaims.Add(claim);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        context.IsActive = true;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

This will add any claim that isn't already on the token.

2. When calling `HttpContext.SignInAsync` you must pass the list of claims, otherwise no additional claims will be in the `context.Subject.Claims` collection.

Comment: If for client_credentials the claim is added, then this means you configured the claim in the ClientClaims table?

Comment: Why should the claim be part of the access_token? It seems more a claim that should be part of the identity_token, though you won't probably find it there either because by default this only contains the sub claim, unless AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken is true: `var token = await _httpContext.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("identity_token");`. Otherwise get the claims from the UserInfo endpoint (using the access token).

Comment: the claim is not part of the access token. I mentioned that on one type of flow the claims are carried on the token successfully and on the other it does not.

Comment: Why are you adding claims to the context.Subject.Claims collection in code ? A more flexible solution would be to persist the claim in the UserClaims table.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg my solution does not use the EF persistant as in documentation and I have written a custom solution wrapping IdentityServer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement custom `IProfileService` if you want to add custom claims to the token.

You can find more info in [Identity Server 4 docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html).

An example of simple custom profile service would be:

```
public class CustomProfileService : IProfileService
{
    public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        context.AddRequestedClaims(context.Subject.Claims);
        context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("MyName", "Ophir"));
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        context.IsActive = true;    
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Once you have this, just register it to the DI:

```
services.AddTransient<IProfileService, CustomProfileService>();
```

It will get called whenever an `access_token` or `id_token` is requested. You would need to check `context.Caller` as per Ruard's comment if you only wanted the extra claims in certain type of token.

**EDIT:**
Also alternatively, you can add the claims directly to the user configuration as per example in one of the [Identity Server 4 quickstarts](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/master/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess/src/IdentityServer/Config.cs):

```
            new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = "1",
                Username = "alice",
                Password = "password",

                Claims = new []
                {
                    new Claim("MyName", "Ophir")
                }
            },
```

If you end up not implementing custom `IProfileService` and keep using `DefaultProfileService`, then you would also need add a custom `IdentityResource` in your configuration:

```
return new List<IdentityResource>
{
    //..Your other configured identity resources

    new IdentityResource(
    name: "custom.name",
    displayName: "Custom Name",
    claimTypes: new[] { "MyName" });
};
```

Any clients wanting to have this claim added in the token would need request for `custom.name` scope.

Comment: There is no _need_ to implement IProfileService. This can be done by configuration only. Also, the above code will actually prevent configured claims from being added, because the line `context.AddRequestedClaims(context.Subject.Claims);` is missing. And without check on Context.Caller this code will add the claim to both the access token and identity token.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Yeah, thanks for pointing these out, I forgot that `context.AddRequestedClaims()` is in their `DefaultProfileService` so that behaviour would have been lost. Good shout on the configuration too, I never personally used User claims in the configuration, I assume they will be added if `profile` scope is requested.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken then by default only _sub_ is returned in the id_token. The UserInfo endpoint should be called to obtain the other claims. To prevent this extra call, when both an id_token and access_token are requested, set AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken to true. Also note that the default profile will not include the claim _MyName_. Add _MyName_ as IdentityClaim to profile (or add a new IdentityResource containing _MyName_ as IdentityClaim, and make sure the scope is requested by the client).

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Yeah, you're not mistaken about any of your comments :), I've just tried this locally.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg how can this be done with configuration and without implementing IProfileService? any examples?

Comment: @developer82 That is not how to implement the IProfileService. You are now dumping _all_ user claims in both tokens, which defeats the purpose of the IdentityServer implementation: to keep tokens small.

Comment: @developer82 the idea is to define resources and use scopes to get certain claims into the token, instead of all claims. As documented here: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html#defining-identity-resources

Answer (score 0):

AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server does not serialize claims that do not have destinations set.  I ran into this when using OpenIdDict.

try this:

```
var claim = new Claim("MyName", "Ophir");
claim.SetDestinations(OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken);

await HttpContext.SignInAsync("anon@nymous.com", "anon@nymous.com", null, claim);
```

You will probably need to add these namespaces:

```
using AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Extensions;
using AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Primitives;
```

Comment: I'm using .NET Core 2.2. Those namespaces does not seem to be valid, and `SetDestinations` and `OpenIdConnectConstants` are unrecognized.

Comment: I've installed the following nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server unfortunately it does not help. I still don't have any claims on my token.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps in which I add  claims to tokens for our identityserver.

Through a custom profile service like one of the other answers shows, you can define your own claims for an user.

Those claims can then be requested through the userinfo endpoint.

Or you create an Api ( resource)  called for example IncludeNameInAccessToken that adds the name claim by default to the access token if you request that Api as a scope.