# Sub claim missing from ProfileDataRequestContext.RequestedClaimTypes

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

In IdentityServer4 I have defined an IdentityResource with some claims:

```
new IdentityResource {
  Name = "userdata",
  UserClaims = new List<string> {
    JwtClaimTypes.Subject,
    JwtClaimTypes.Role,
    JwtClaimTypes.Email,
    JwtClaimTypes.Name
  }
}
```

And then add it to the scopes in the client configuration:

```
AllowedScopes = {
  IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
  "api1",
  "userdata"
}
```

In the client app I requested that scope:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => {
  options.Scope.Add("openid");
  options.Scope.Add("userdata");
  options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
  options.Scope.Add("api1");
}
```

In IS4 I have implemented *IProfileService* to add some claims to the id_token.

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context) {

  var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
  var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
  if (user == null) {
    throw new ArgumentException("");
  }

  var principal = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);
  var userClaims = principal.Claims.ToList();

  var claims = new List<Claim> {
    userClaims.Find(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Subject),
    userClaims.Find(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Role),
    userClaims.Find(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Email),
    userClaims.Find(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Name),
    new Claim("iesseapetenantid", user.TenantId.ToString())
  };

  var requestedClaimTypes = context.RequestedClaimTypes;

  context.AddRequestedClaims(claims);
}
```

`context.AddRequestedClaims(claims)` filter the claims passed and add only the ones requested by the client.

The problem is that in `context.RequestedClaimTypes` the *sub* claim is missing but the other three are there: *email*, *name* and *role*.

[image]

Why is the "sub" claim missing?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no need to implement IProfileService if you just want to add some claims. Take a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54910744/identityserver4-claims-are-not-part-of-the-token-on-hybrid-flow#answer-54912933).

Comment: @RuardvanElburg In my case I need to implement `IProfileService` because I want to inject some claims dynamically. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sub` claim is the one required by the [spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken), so it's a part of the `StandardScopes.OpenId`. You do not need to setup or request it additionally.

```cs
var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
```

assumes that the `sub` claim is already within the context. If not, an exception will be thrown.

All above is about `IdentityResource` and `id_token`. A `token` for `ApiResource` may be created without referencing a user.

Comment: Yes, i get that, but the problem remains. RequestedClaimTypes doesn't contains the sub claim even if i have requested the OpenId scope. So it's not added to the id_token.

Comment: hmm, these are two different points: `RequestedClaimTypes` should not contain `sub`, that's for additional user claims only. but the token has to include the `sub`

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly said that sub wasn't in the id_token. The important part is, as you said, that `RequestedClaimTypes` is for **additional user claims** only. That's what confused me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in the claims mapping config.

Just add a line

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("sub");
```

before

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
```